# How can I record merely Heads in a video call?

Tags: screen-recording

To save Hard Drive space, how can I record merely the green rectangles below containing heads?

I waste bytes if I record the areas crossed out in orange, like the backgrounds and shoulders. See screenshot below [from Skype's video](https://youtu.be/cjmdX4ZYKAw). Don't hesitate to answer this for other video chat apps like Zoom!

[image]

Comment: You don't really waste much data at all, because video basically only records anything that's *moved* since the last frame. A static background will use very little data compared to the constantly moving heads.

Comment: Would you mind clarifying what is the video source? Whole screen capture? Video file on your hard drive? Skype proprietary video stream? Zoom stream?

Comment: @NicolasRaoul Our family and I need to capture from live Skype and Zoom. We use both. NO, not whole screen capture.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[Opencv](https://opencv.org/) is a library that supports recognition of items or faces.

There are several applications based on opencv as well as a documentation for [cropping faces](https://docs.opencv.org/3.4/de/d27/tutorial_table_of_content_face.html).

I've worked with OpenCV in conjunction with python and found it easy to use